# Software to scrape or crawl for website urls

Tags: web-scraping, web-crawler

I want to scrape/crawl (don't know which one is best translation) website urls. For example i want to get every urls from:
`www.Site.com/posts.html` which contains `www.Site.com/2015-04-01/1`

So I would type in software `www.Site.com` and set depth to `2` and required url text `www.Site.com/2015-04-01/1`

So.. Software should:

1. go to: `www.Site.com/posts.html`
2. Find matched urls: Lets say it find:

   - `www.Site.com/2015-04-01/1/Working-Stuff.html`
   - `www.Site.com/2015-04-01/1/New-stuff.html`
   - `www.Site.com/2015-04-01/1/News.html`

And now it goes to first matched url (a) and look for another urls which contains `www.Site.com/2015-04-01/1`.

So for example it would look like this:

```
Main site: `www.Site.com/posts.html`


    1)www.Site.com/2015-04-01/1/Working-Stuff.html
        1a) www.Site.com/2015-04-01/1/Break.htm
        1b) www.Site.com/2015-04-01/1/How-to.htm
        1c) www.Site.com/2015-04-01/1/Lets-say.htm
        1d) www.Site.com/2015-04-01/1/Gamer-life.htm

    2) www.Site.com/2015-04-01/1/New-stuff.html
        2a) www.Site.com/2015-04-01/1/My-Story-about.htm

    3) www.Site.com/2015-04-01/1/News.html
        3a) www.Site.com/2015-04-01/1/Go-to-hell.htm
        3b) www.Site.com/2015-04-01/1/Leave.htm
```

Of course I don't need that prefix grouping 1), 2), 2a) etc. I want to grab only urls.

I used:

A1 website scraper - but when I try to scrape from `......html` it cuts `.html` part and does not giving me full url list :/

Comment: Sorry, bad question. Please read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0):

[**edited my previous slightly simplistic answer**]

Screen scraping is the process of removing data from a web page. The R package **rvest** is very good at screen scraping.

Web crawling is the process of traversing through a website moving from page to page. The R package **rselenium** is very good at mimicking user's movement from page to page, but only when you know the structure of the web site.

You sound like you want to do a crawl from page to page, starting from a head page and moving forward. I think that you could code this up using a combination of the [rvest](https://blog.rstudio.org/2014/11/24/rvest-easy-web-scraping-with-r/) and [rselenium](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSelenium/vignettes/RSelenium-basics.html) packages. Between the two of these you can customise and take any particular unknown route.